# Where can I find the directory of all my posts/articles in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, directory, file-structure

I think all the posts should be in wp-content/uploads/... But I couldn't find them. Anyone has ideas of where my posts are located? Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't they be stored in a database?

Comment: Oh yeah I totally forgot the database... Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

When you say "posts" are you referring to the default post type "post", (the post tab in your admin panel)?

If this is what you're referring to, you can access them directly through your database. All posts are stored in your database and not as actual files.

If you need to access them via your templates you can use one of two wordpress methods:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post
);
```

The args array will be your settings for the queries.

```
$posts = get_posts($args);
print_r($posts); // this will give you 5 posts, you can increase the number with the argument 'posts_per_page' => x
```

you can loop through this data with a simple foreach.

The second method:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
         //post data (title, content, etc...)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Comment: Can anyone tell us where to execute those functions? I mean in which file?